# HP EVA4400 Vraid5 Virtual Disks Failure

Tags: storage, hp

I have a eva4400 with 8 disks six of them in a raid6 group

I have 2 vraid5 in this group.

I have lost 3 disks.

Since I get the administrator post after the disaster happened I have no clue on how where the disks distributed on eva but, I notice that I have 2 disks failed in the disk group, 1 disk failed on Ungrouped disks, and 1 good drive also in Ungrouped disks.

I dont now if the 2 disks (the good and the bad) where in the ungrouped disks from the start

I bought 3 new disks from HP and place them in so now I have 4 good disks on ungrouped disks and 1 bad disk and also still 2 bad disks on disk group

Since I have no support from HP is there anything I can do to save the data from failed vraid5 diks?
Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

> is there anything I can do to save the data from failed vraid5 disks?

No, you'll have to restore from backup sorry.

That said I did just want to clarify that you meant you have 8 disks, 1 disk group with two spares and two virtual disks using VRAID5 - is that right? I just wanted to get the terminology right as your question wasn't as clear as it could be.

Can I suggest that when you get this back up and running you configure the disk group to only have a single spare, not double - not for such a small array. Then use either VRAID 6 or 10 (0+1 actually), they're much more resilient than VRAID 5.

Oh and on one final note - these aren't the 1TB FATA disks are they? a few years ago we saw a ridiculous number of these fail, many at the same time - due to miscommunicated duty-cycle requirements - we abandoned using those disks. I'm just keen to help you avoid a repeat of this issue.

Comment: Well yes I have 1 disk group with 6 disks and 2 ungrouped disks. The question is that since 2 disks died in group and I had 2 disks in ungrouped disks could the system just use them as spares? The disk are 300GB FC.. I have no backup in place :( Is anything that can be done?

Comment: If they'd been grouped as spares they woyld have been used yes, but ungrouped they'll just sit there, there is nothing that can be done.